# Monotouch: Universal app?

Tags: xamarin.ios

Does Monotouch support the iPhone/iPad "universal app"?  If so, where can I find the docs on how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course! Miguel De Icaza has done a very good job with Monotouch.

Under Project settings, select IPhone Application and then specify the target for your application: IPad only, IPhone only or both.

Rembember that when you want to create an universal app, you have to provide specific sizes for each device (views, orientations,images and so on).

To check the current device and customize your app for iPad and iPhone you can use the following property and verify if it contains ipad string. You can create a global boolean variable (a static variable for example and check the if your app is running on iPhone or iPad). To test run with the right simulator: obviously iPhone or iPad simulator.

```
UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Model
```

Cheers.

Comment: So, I would still need new xib's (like for split screen, etc)... also would pretty much have to follow the design methodology if I were using XCode (separating shared code, etc), right?

Comment: In my opinion you can follow two ways. The first one is to create different interfaces for both devices and then istantiate them based on that boolean value. The second one is to use the boolean value for providing a different size to every view you are creating. For example in portrait mode: if(isPad) aView = new UIView(new RectangleF(0,0,768,1024)) else ...; Maybe the first solution will be more simple to reach but it would increase the app dimension (in byte). Then second one is more difficult to achieve. In this case you have to do the job programatically. Hope this helps. Cheers.